# Make image view resize to wrap content after performing matrix transform

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm creating an image view like so (this code is running inside a custom view I have created that extends `FrameLayout` - hence the call to `addView` at the end to add the dynamically created image view to the `FrameLayout`):

```
val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, resourceId)
    ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("$resourceId is not a valid resourceId")

val view = ImageView(context).apply {
    layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX
    setImageDrawable(drawable)
}

addView(view)
```

So far, so good. It renders as expected, the `ImageView`s width/height wrap the content of the supplied drawable.

Now, I want to perform some matrix transformations on this image (based on the user dragging the item  round) and this is where I ran into problems.

The actual transforms I want to apply are more complex than what I'm about to describe, but the issue I was observing can also be replicated by doing a simple scale transform, so I'll show the code for that to keep the question concise. Also, let's pretend it's not the user dragging the item that triggers the transform, and we'll just assume I apply the transform after a user taps the `ImageView` for simplicities sake.

So, when the user taps the `ImageView` I run the following code:

```
val transformMatrix = Matrix()
transformMatrix.set(resource.initialMatrix)
transformMatrix.setScale(2f, 2f)
(v as ImageView).imageMatrix = transformMatrix
```

And, what I observe is, the image does indeed scale up 2x, but, the view itself doesn't update it's width/height to wrap the content of the now scaled image.

I don't want to set the `ImageView`s width/height to `MATCH_PARENT` for multiple reasons, I simply want its width/height to wrap the contents of the image it is rendering.

I am assuming this is caused because the canvas of the image view is not updating when the matrix transform is applied? Also, I cannot easily know up front what the maximum width/height of my view needs to be because in reality the transforms I want to apply are quite dynamic (a function of the x/y position of the view relative to it's initial position).

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried using `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work. That tells the image to keep it's original aspect ratio, which won't work for my wanted transforms as I am using `matrix.setPolyToPoly` (in effect, "warping" the image). If i use `adjustViewBounds = true` then my transforms don't appear to work and I just end up with a square image. This may work for a simple scale transform (as I posted in my question) but it does not when applying complex transform via `matrix.setPolyToPoly`